# Javadoc error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, javadoc

Im trying to create a Javadoc but i can't.

I have written my comments in swedish så they content charachters as å,ä,ö.
This is giving me over 248 erros.

Is there a way to change the encoding for the whole Project?

I have tried:

1. Right-clicked on the project
2. Choosed Resource
3. Change to UTF-8
4. Restarted Eclipse
5. Create new Javadoc

This results in the following error:

> error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII

Is there something else i can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Specifying UTF-8 as your resource encoding is a good thing to do, but you may also perform the following:

If you generate your Javadoc using `javadoc` binary, you may check its `-encoding` parameter:

```
javadoc: 
usage: javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
...
-encoding <name>          Source file encoding name
```

**Using Eclipse**, you may specify this option in field "`Extra Javadoc options (...):`" in last Wizard step (example: `-encoding UTF-8`).

Comment: I got the same error from the java compiler and found that `javac -encoding utf-8 ...`  works in that case, too.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old question, but maybe it would be helpful for someone.
I want to add something to [Xav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599043/5694159) (I cannot add comments so I write answer):

Javadoc gives you following description (javadoc -help):

```
-encoding <name>    Source file encoding name
-charset <charset>  Charset for cross-platform viewing of generated documentation
```

"-encoding" parameter indicates how to read characters. You can also use "-charset" option to making your HTML documentation more readable.